How to run a .bat file from excel vba
I have a .bat file that runs if I double click on it. But it doesn't run when I try to run it from Excel vba like this:
Const BatchfileName = "C:\Users\TB\Desktop\UpdateReports_NEWDB\myBatch.bat"
Dim wsh2 As Object
Set wsh2 = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn2 As Boolean: waitOnReturn2 = True
Dim windowStyle2 As Integer: windowStyle2 = 1 'To minimize the Command prompt window use 2, to hide it use 0 (zero),to show it type 1(one)
wsh2.Run BatchfileName, windowStyle2, waitOnReturn2

I am trying to run it on windows 10 32bit. I am mentioning this because I have another laptop with windows 10 64bit and it runs from excel vba there. Do I need to have R on my path in order to run this shell?
BatchfileName contains: cd %1 R CMD BATCH current_model.r

You don't need WScript. Use VBA's built-in Shell command instead. There are many existing samples of doing so here at SO if you search for them. Also, when executing batch files from another application, you typically need to use cmd batchfilename.bat with one of cmd's available switches, which you can find by running cmd /? from a command prompt.

I actually tried Shell "R CMD BATCH BatchfileName.bat", vbNormalFocus and I get the message that the file is not found, However, I hardcoded the path to myBatch.bat. I like to use WScript because it waits for other processes to finish.

I have no idea what R CMD BATCH means. CMD is the Windows cmd.exe, which is what interprets and runs batch scripts. It's used like cmd /c myBatch.bat. Replace the /c with whatever one of the supported switches you need, which I've told you already how to find. Whatever the R CMD BATCH is that you tried is a mystery to me, and has nothing to do with the sample code you provided in your question, which has nothing containing R anywhere in it (well, until you just edited it in).

R CMD BATCH can be used from excel vba inside the shell as well. However, not sure why is not working today on my 32bit laptop.

@KenWhite R is the R language

I suppose "myBatch.bat" is
cd %1
R CMD BATCH current_model.r

Thus, you need to provide a path as the single parameter for this file.
Const BatchfileName = "C:\Users\TB\Desktop\UpdateReports_NEWDB\myBatch.bat"
Const path = "C:\Users\TB\Desktop\UpdateReports_NEWDB" ' replace it with the actual path you need

Shell "cmd /c " & BatchfileName & " " & path, vbNormalFocus

Consider what cd doesn't change the current drive. If the path refers to another drive, you need to change the current drive first.
If the (current) folder content isn't required for R, you can run
Shell "R CMD BATCH path\current_model.r", vbNormalFocus

replacing 'path' by the actual path to 'current_model.r'.

I always run it like this Shell "R CMD BATCH current_model.r" without hard coding the path because the Excel book and the r script live in the same folder. However, my 32bit laptop want full paths to Rscript and full paths to the workbook. I don't understand why dynamic path isn't working.
